# Any documentation for Surecom EP-824DX-CS?

Tags: networking, switch

I must find some documentation for a Surecom **EP-824DX-CS** (24-Port 100/10M N-Way 19" Rach-Mount Smart Switch) in order to find the capabilities of the device, but the most important is the console port pinout (DB-9 male). Also, the device has some sort of administration method (telnet/http) ?

Comment: Have you tried contacting any of the vendors that still sell them?

Comment: I couldn't find any web site for Surecom, and the switch seems to be out of stock on every site I could find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an FTP repository that has all their manuals: ftp://ftp.ral.ro/Public/Support/surecom/Manual/

More specifically, the EP-824DX-CS manual is split in the two following files:

- ftp://ftp.ral.ro/Public/Support/surecom/Manual/824DXCS-1.pdf
- ftp://ftp.ral.ro/Public/Support/surecom/Manual/824DXCS-2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it looks like the company [no longer exists](http://getsatisfaction.com/surecomsolutions/topics/usa_company_surecom_solutions_not_affiliated_with_surecom_of_taiwan). If you are just trying to get into the admin mode I suggest you either try [HyperTerminal](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736511.aspx) through the serial port or the telnet admin. There is likely a reset button on the switch, hold that for a few moments and then let it 'boot' up.

If you are prompted for a password I would go through all the standard network device [password lists](http://www.phenoelit-us.org/dpl/dpl.html). Most companies use 'admin' or 'password', or a combination.

Comment: It doesn't have any buttons, and I'm not sure what kind of cable is needed to connect to the console port. Thank you for the password list.

Comment: A standard Serial Cable (RS232) cable is the norm for a 9-pin connector. Port looks like http://www.aggsoft.com/rs232-pinout-cable/images/9-pinout.gif, cable looks like https://www.kellycontroller.com/shop/images/products/RS232Cable.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I have something (pdf) but not for this model -not CS but FS. If You steel  need that I can send You on mail that instruction.I have manual for switch and instruction how login to switch ,config conection  etc.Manual is not to good but if you have something its better then nothing:-)
BTW Here I found circuit power block and how it repair .
http://www.radioamator.ru/publ/ehlektropitanie/remont_blokov_pitanija/remont_impulsnogo_bloka_pitanija_24_portovogo_svitcha_surecom/46-1-0-718 
Google translator help You.
I`m from Poland 
Bogdan